# FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "MY_IP", user "MY_USER", database "MY_DB", SSL on / off (PG::ConnectionBad)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I have rails application uses postgres as the database and capistrano for deployment tool. I managed to deploy it in AWS EC2 last week but this week I encounter this error. I didn't know why it suddenly error occur without touching pg_hba.conf or any files in the server. I'm bit frustrated now as really don't know how to fix this. I already open the host as all in the pg_hba.conf but still not working.

There are 2 EC2 instances

1 is where I deploy the application then the other 1 is where the database   serve.

Comment: Can you connect to your database manually on your EC2 instance? (Either through the command line locally/remotely or through a GUI tool)

Comment: Yes, I can manually connect on the EC2 using the pgadmin.

Comment: Can you take a look at `listen_address`? Also, can you update OP with `pg_hba.conf`